# ServiceStack.Text and Twitter JSON

Tags: c#, servicestack, deserialization, servicestack-text

I am attempting to deserialize the twitter RateLimit Json with ServiceStack.Text.  I created an appropriate DTO object (look at the bottom of the post) for the JSON getting pulled down.  I made use of System.Runtime.Serialization to rename the fields to more friendly names (I have used this in many other DTO objects from Twitter).  When deserializing the object, the RateLimitContext deserializes properly, however all items under Resources deserialize to null.  I suspect there is something wrong with the DataMemberNames for this particular object, since they contain several "special" characters.  Is this a bug in ServiceStack.Text or am I missing something in my DTO?

```
[DataContract]
public class RateLimitResult
{
    [DataMember(Name = "rate_limit_context")]
    public RateLimitContextEntry RateLimitContext { get; set; }

    [DataContract]
    public class RateLimitContextEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "resources")]
    public ResourcesEntry Resources { get; set; }

    [DataContract]
    public class RateLimitEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "remaining")]
        public int Remaining { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "reset")]
        public long Reset { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "limit")]
        public int Limit { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class HelpEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/help/privacy")]
        public RateLimitEntry Privacy { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/help/configuration")]
        public RateLimitEntry Configuration { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/help/tos")]
        public RateLimitEntry Tos { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/help/languages")]
        public RateLimitEntry Languages { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class StatusesEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/statuses/oembed")]
        public RateLimitEntry Oembed { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/statuses/user_timeline")]
        public RateLimitEntry UserTimeline { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/statuses/mentions_timeline")]
        public RateLimitEntry MentionsTimeline { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/statuses/home_timeline")]
        public RateLimitEntry HomeTimeline { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/statuses/show/:id")]
        public RateLimitEntry ShowId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/statuses/retweets/:id")]
        public RateLimitEntry RetweetsId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/statuses/retweets_of_me")]
        public RateLimitEntry RetweetsOfMe { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class UsersEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/users/search")]
        public RateLimitEntry Search { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/users/suggestions")]
        public RateLimitEntry Suggestions { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/users/contributors")]
        public RateLimitEntry Contributors { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/users/suggestions/:slug/members")]
        public RateLimitEntry SuggestionsSlugMembers { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/users/suggestions/:slug")]
        public RateLimitEntry SuggestionsSlug { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/users/contributees")]
        public RateLimitEntry Contributees { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/users/lookup")]
        public RateLimitEntry Lookup { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/users/profile_banner")]
        public RateLimitEntry ProfileBanner { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SearchEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/search/tweets")]
        public RateLimitEntry Tweets { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class TrendsEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/trends/available")]
        public RateLimitEntry Available { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/trends/place")]
        public RateLimitEntry Place { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/trends/closest")]
        public RateLimitEntry Closest { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class SavedSearchesEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/saved_searches/destroy/:id")]
        public RateLimitEntry DestroyId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/saved_searches/list")]
        public RateLimitEntry List { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/saved_searches/show/:id")]
        public RateLimitEntry ShowId { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FavoritesEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/favorites/list")]
        public RateLimitEntry List { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class AccountEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/account/verify_credentials")]
        public RateLimitEntry VerifyCredentials { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/account/settings")]
        public RateLimitEntry Settings { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DirectMessagesEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/direct_messages/show")]
        public RateLimitEntry Show { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/direct_messages/sent_and_received")]
        public RateLimitEntry SentAndReceived { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/direct_messages/sent")]
        public RateLimitEntry Sent { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/direct_messages")]
        public RateLimitEntry Messages { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FriendsEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/friends/ids")]
        public RateLimitEntry Ids { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/friends/list")]
        public RateLimitEntry List { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FollowersEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/followers/list")]
        public RateLimitEntry List { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/followers/ids")]
        public RateLimitEntry Ids { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class PromptsEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/prompts/record_event")]
        public RateLimitEntry RecordEvent { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/prompts/suggest")]
        public RateLimitEntry Suggest { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class GeoEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/geo/similar_places")]
        public RateLimitEntry SimilarPlaces { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/geo/search")]
        public RateLimitEntry Search { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/geo/reverse_geocode")]
        public RateLimitEntry ReverseGeocode { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/geo/id/:place_id")]
        public RateLimitEntry PlaceId { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class BlocksEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/blocks/ids")]
        public RateLimitEntry Ids { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/blocks/list")]
        public RateLimitEntry List { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class FriendshipsEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/friendships/incoming")]
        public RateLimitEntry Incoming { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/friendships/lookup")]
        public RateLimitEntry Lookup { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/friendships/outgoing")]
        public RateLimitEntry Outgoing { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/friendships/no_retweets/ids")]
        public RateLimitEntry NoRetweetsIds { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/friendships/show")]
        public RateLimitEntry Show { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ApplicationEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/application/rate_limit_status")]
        public RateLimitEntry RateLimitStatus { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ListsEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/subscribers")]
        public RateLimitEntry Subscribers { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/list")]
        public RateLimitEntry List { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/memberships")]
        public RateLimitEntry Memberships { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/ownerships")]
        public RateLimitEntry Ownerships { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/subscriptions")]
        public RateLimitEntry Subscriptions { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/members")]
        public RateLimitEntry Members { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/subscribers/show")]
        public RateLimitEntry ShowSubscribers { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/statuses")]
        public RateLimitEntry Statuses { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/members/show")]
        public RateLimitEntry ShowMembers { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "/lists/show")]
        public RateLimitEntry Show { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ResourcesEntry
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "lists")]
        public ListsEntry Lists { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "application")]
        public ApplicationEntry Application { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "friendships")]
        public FriendshipsEntry Friendships { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "blocks")]
        public BlocksEntry Blocks { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "geo")]
        public GeoEntry Geo { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "users")]
        public UsersEntry Users { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "prompts")]
        public PromptsEntry Prompts { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "followers")]
        public FollowersEntry Followers { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "statuses")]
        public StatusesEntry Statuses { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "help")]
        public HelpEntry Help { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "friends")]
        public FriendsEntry Friends { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "direct_messages")]
        public DirectMessagesEntry DirectMessages { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "account")]
        public AccountEntry Account { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "favorites")]
        public FavoritesEntry Favorites { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "saved_searches")]
        public SavedSearchesEntry SavedSearches { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "search")]
        public SearchEntry Search { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "trends")]
        public TrendsEntry Trends { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is sample Json returned by the API:

```
{
"rate_limit_context": {
    "access_token": "ajksldjalsda-akjflkasjfltpowfaalksjdfAPQPIJFaflkjaq"
},
"resources": {
    "lists": {
        "/lists/subscribers": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/list": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/memberships": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/ownerships": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/subscriptions": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/members": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/subscribers/show": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/statuses": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/members/show": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/lists/show": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "application": {
        "/application/rate_limit_status": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 178,
            "reset": 1380314022
        }
    },
    "friendships": {
        "/friendships/incoming": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/friendships/lookup": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/friendships/outgoing": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/friendships/no_retweets/ids": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/friendships/show": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "blocks": {
        "/blocks/ids": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/blocks/list": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "geo": {
        "/geo/similar_places": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/geo/search": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/geo/reverse_geocode": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/geo/id/:place_id": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "/users/profile_banner": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/suggestions/:slug/members": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/show/:id": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/suggestions": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/lookup": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/search": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/contributors": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/contributees": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/users/suggestions/:slug": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "prompts": {
        "/prompts/record_event": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/prompts/suggest": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "followers": {
        "/followers/list": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/followers/ids": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "statuses": {
        "/statuses/mentions_timeline": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/statuses/show/:id": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/statuses/oembed": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/statuses/retweeters/ids": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/statuses/home_timeline": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/statuses/user_timeline": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/statuses/retweets/:id": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/statuses/retweets_of_me": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "help": {
        "/help/privacy": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/help/tos": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/help/configuration": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/help/languages": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "friends": {
        "/friends/ids": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/friends/list": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "direct_messages": {
        "/direct_messages/show": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/direct_messages/sent_and_received": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/direct_messages/sent": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/direct_messages": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "account": {
        "/account/verify_credentials": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/account/settings": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "favorites": {
        "/favorites/list": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "saved_searches": {
        "/saved_searches/destroy/:id": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/saved_searches/list": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/saved_searches/show/:id": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "search": {
        "/search/tweets": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 180,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    },
    "trends": {
        "/trends/available": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/trends/place": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        },
        "/trends/closest": {
            "limit": 15,
            "remaining": 15,
            "reset": 1380314146
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`[DataMember]` Name's are only for specifying a **single** fieldname alias, i.e. they're not nested and can't contain non-alphanumeric chars as you've done here.

Here's an example of [Twitter DTOs for use in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/Models/TwitterDtos.cs) serializers.

Comment: I should have mentioned, JSON.Net had no issues with these field names.  I only ran into this issue when I attempted to swap deserializers.

Comment: I updated the post with sample Json returned by the API.  Do you have any suggestions on handling those field names?

Comment: Use a property that matches the JSON like `Dictionary<string, PocoWithLimitRemainingReset> Lists` or [parse it dynamically](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#supports-dynamic-json)